# Extend strip to current position (or marker) in VSE

Tags: video-sequence-editor

What is the name of the action that allows you to extend a strip in the video sequence editor, that can be done by right clicking on the strip handle and dragging the mouse to the desired position?

Where would it be in a menu?

I am looking to create a keyboard shortcut that would allow me to extend a strip in the same way that Shift+S snaps the strip to the current position.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you select start point of strip instead of full strip, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> will do exactly what you want:

[image]